# Download Excel from MemoryStream data in a Non-Controller Method in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `.Net Unit Testing Class` where I'm calling a method called `WriteToExcel()` from a `TestMethod`. Inside the `WriteToExcel()`, I have a MemoryStream of data - `memoryStream`. I want to write this `memorystream data` to a blank already existing excel file / download the file to local.

```
public void WriteToExcel(){
....
....
File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx"); 
}
```

In the last statement of the WriteToExcel() i.e. `File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");`, I get this error (below screenshot):

[image]

I have tried adding `using System.Web.Mvc;`(because `File` resides in this assembly) but the error doesn't go. How else can I download the file / write the data to a blank excel?

Comment: Post the actual code. The error complains that you tried to use an instance method from a *static* method. You wouldn't get that error if you used `File` in a controller action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos yes, exactly, that's the problem..I'm not calling it from a controller action method..like I mentioned, I'm calling WriteToExcel() from an Unit Test Method

Comment: This method isn't testable because there's no way to validate the contents of the stream. You don't return anything or rely on an injected service that could be mocked.